# What does “Church’s darkest existential problem in an era of existential problems” mean?

Tags: meaning

There was the following sentence in Time magazine’s (December 11, 2013) article titled, “Pope Francis, the people’s Pope.”]]

> “On December 5, in a long overdue move, the group of eight named a new
>   commission on sex abuse, the problem of priest preying on children
>   they had vowed to protect. **It is the Church’s darkest existential problem
>   in an era of existential problems**. The commission aims to study better ways to protect
>   children, screen programs that involve children and suggest new ways
>   to create safe environments and choose the priest to lead them.”
>   http://poy.time.com/2013/12/11/person-of-the-year-pope-francis-the-peoples-pope/

I’m not clear with what the word, “existential” specifically means in the above context.

Oxford Advanced Learner’s Dictionary defines ‘existential;

1. Connected with **human existence**.
2. (Philosophy) connected with **the theory of existentialism**.

Which definition of the above does better apply to the “existential problem(s)” of the above quote? Are there any other interpretations than the above two?

Comment: Exactly what difference do you understand between those two definitions? I don't see a distinction worth bothering with. You might as well ask whether there's any significant difference between your cited *the Church* and the British Anglican Church (or the Baptists, or Methodists, or whatever).

Comment: @FumbleFingers Reading in context, I think the asker wants to know about the *Roman Catholic Church*. The Pope cannot be anything other than Catholic.

Comment: @Anonymous: Judging by the number of times I've been asked [Is the Pope Catholic?](https://www.google.co.uk/search?hl=en&source=hp&q=is+the+pope+catholic&aq=f&aqi=g5g-z1g4&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=), I wouldn't be too sure everyone else is as clued-up as you on that particular question!

Comment: @FumbleFingers https://www.google.com/search?q=pope&rlz=1C1CHNU_enUS337US337&oq=pope&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l2j69i60l2j0.1002j0j7&sourceid=chrome&espv=210&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8

Comment: @Oldcat - you're right. I've removed my answer.

Comment: In this context, since the Pope believes in God and His laws, it can only mean existence. I agree with Oldcat; his description of the problems as existential does nothing to improve the meaning of his statement.

Comment: @Susan: I shall fawn over you forever!

Comment: I have little problem imagining that the writer in Time either does not know what the word means, or that he tossed it in twice  to add false majesty to his article.

Comment: FumbleFingers. My question is: Does ‘existential problem(s)’ refers to (1) plain ‘physical’ problem concerning life or death / presence, or extinction of  Church, or (2)‘philosophical’ problem – dealt by  such as Søren Kierkegaard, Nietzsche and Sartre, or other than both (1) and(2)?

Answer (score 3):

I think they mean ["existential crisis"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Existential_crisis):

> An existential crisis is a moment at which an individual questions the very foundations of their life: whether their life has any meaning, purpose or value.

It makes some sense here; if the Catholic Church can't protect children from its priests, how can it justify its existence?

Comment: The Church isn't an individual and can't have such a thing.  Each member might, but it can't.

Comment: @Oldcat: Googling *"its existential crisis"*, we learn that the eurozone, the publishing industry, Airtel, Starbucks, capitalism, and the Republican Party can all have existential crises. If this is an abuse of the phrase, it's a very common one.

Comment: And in a reference back to the original subject, a widespread abuse is worse than an uncommon one!

Comment: I don't see why non-human social entities can't have existential crises... Such entities can come in and out of existence and there can be pivotal moments behind this. See for instance the Federalist Party and Whig Party in America, the Mormons regarding desegregation.

Comment: Furthermore, if an expression can be established as common, then it can't be deemed incorrect, personal preferences notwithstanding. Otherwise, we will descend into the cesspool of prescriptivism.

Comment: It's not totally clear, but while institutions can have existential crises in the existentialism sense, I think here it means a problem that threatens the church's very existence, rather than a problem that threatens its concept of self; there is a similar usage in the phrase [existential threat](https://www.dictionary.com/e/pop-culture/existential-threat/).

Comment: The difference between "problem" and "crisis" is largely one of scale. If it is possible to have an "existential crisis" then it is also possible to have an "existential problem". Just because one is a well-known phrase doesn't make the other incorrect.

Comment: @DJClayworth: My impression was that *existential crisis* was, like *midlife crisis*, one of those fixed phrases where you can't change the wording without doing serious harm to the meaning. For example, a *midlife problem* is needing glasses to read; a *midlife crisis* is going out and buying a red convertible.

Comment: Yes. But just because "existential crisis" is a well known phrase that doesn't mean "existential problem" is not a valid thing. Likewise a "midlife problem" is a valid phrase, despite the popularity of the phrase "midlife crisis".

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like this word means nothing in this context. You can drop both "existential"s and the sentence loses nothing by it.

Comment: I'd go along with that. I see more significance in the fact that apparently Time chose *not* to capitalise *the Church* (my edit to the Q was therefore *wrong*, since I edited the capital in assuming that OP had mistranscribed it). Whatever next? Will be be reading an item about **the bible** in **time** magazine soon?

Comment: But if an institution has a dark problem it does not necessarily mean that its very existence is in danger. The article is reminding us that the Church and whom it is said to represent, God, is a *dying* one. Atheism is becoming widespread, be it for better or worse, and the failure of the Church to act severly upon peadophile priests is seen to be a contributing factor to its demise.

Comment: "Threatening your existence" isn't what 'existential' means, though.  And the Church has a billion or so members, it is hardly dying even in the USA, no matter how much the press wants you to think.

Comment: On the contrary, *existential* has a definite purpose in this sentence. Drop it and you lose part of the meaning. The sentence isn't referring to just any problem, but one that calls into question the continued existance of the church (or the justification for its continued existance). -1 if I had enough reputation to downvote.

Comment: definition: **of or relating to existence.
concerned with existence, esp. human existence as viewed in the theories of existentialism.** Therefore the article is saying, and I agree with Scott severance, that the Church is suffering a crisis. Europe in particular is deserting the Church in its droves. People, in Italy, no longer go to mass, that's a fact. The only time you see a full church are at weddings and at funerals. That's not the press telling me, that's my experience. The same and more so in the UK, Ireland and France.

Comment: Italy also has a problem with not having enough people in general. The Church is not a human, and can't really have a crisis involving human existence. It is an organization and will die when people leave it, for whatever reason.  The Church is not a follower of existentialism and its theories have no bearing on it whatsoever.

Comment: Another issue is that the article mentions **more than one** such problems, the issue of sexual abuse being merely the darkest. So now you have to come up with a number of such critical, Church destroying issues in order to make sense of the sentence.

Answer (score 0):

It is in a sense both.

*Existential* means, broadly, “characteristic of or concerned with existence”; but since the 1940s phrases like *existential question* and *existential problem* and *existential crisis* have meant questions and problems and crises of the sort discussed by the philosophers called *Existentialists*.

The catchphrase often recited as the core of Existentialism is “Existence precedes essence”. That is, the Existentialists rejected the notion, which for centuries lay at the core of Western philosophy (and particularly of the Catholic Church), that “Essence precedes existence”—that man is defined by ‘humankindness’, by membership in the class ‘human’, and there is thus a quality of being, an ‘essence’, to which the individual is called upon to shape his life and actions, his existence-in-the-world. No, said the Existentialists: the individual is free, is-in-the-world from the outset, and spends existence in creating a unique personal essence through action.

The author is saying, then, that the pederasty scandal confronts the Church with a problem which goes to the very heart of its fundamental identity—one which cannot be resolved by theological casuistry, by contemplation of the Will of God as defined by the Fathers of the Church, but only in its concrete actions in-the-world.

Answer (score 0):

Public School Teachers 100 Times More Likely To Abuse Kids Than Catholic Priests
New data shows that teachers are more likely to abuse kids than Catholic Priests, shining light on a disturbing growing trend in public schools. --Just saw this article this morning!!!

The use of the word 'existential" in this sense harkens to the problem of death in Existentialism so it s mainly connotative and not denotative. Note also that it is incorrectly used to imply a threat to existence, a confusing but common use in political writing.

My cavil with the answers here is that a non-existential problem would not be a problem at all.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the Oxford Advanced Learners is simplifying the definition a little. Other dictionaries have definitions such as:

- [relating to existence or being alive](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/existential)
- [of, or relating to, existence](https://www.britannica.com/dictionary/eb/qa/the-meaning-of-existential)
- [of, relating to, or affirming existence](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/existential)

Some dictionaries specify *human* existence but the word is certainly used for other entities.

**An "existential problem" means a problem that relates to the existence of the thing referred to** - here meaning the church. Usually this means a problem that threatens its existence. An alternative (but related) meaning is to the philosophy of Existentialism. The adjective "existential" can apply to many nouns - there can be " existential threat" "existential question", "existential crisis". [This article considers these three to be the most common uses](https://www.britannica.com/dictionary/eb/qa/the-meaning-of-existential) - the second and third are related to the philosophy, but the first is not. "Existential crisis" is a common phrase (and not always accurately used), but that doesn't invalidate other uses.

In my opinion the paragraph you quote is not about Existentialism the philosophy, but a variant on the first meaning - **this is a problem that threatens the very existence of the church**.