# Why is it “From Dublin to Los Angeles” in the Western world, that has left the church moribund in 20 century culture wars?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, metaphors, metonyms

In connection with [my previous question about the meaning of “the Church’s **existential** problem”](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/148791), there was the following sentence in the same article of *Time Magazine* (December 11, 2013) — “Pope Francis, The People’s Pope.”

> “Through these conscious and skillful evocations of moments in the
>   ministry of Jesus, as recounted in the Gospels, this new Pope may have
>   found a way out of the 20th century culture wars, which have left the
>   church moribund in much of Western Europe and on the defensive **from
>   Dublin to Los Angeles**.”

http://poy.time.com/2013/12/11/person-of-the-year-pope-francis-the-peoples-pope/

As I have no knowledge about Christianity, I can’t make out why Dublin and Los Angeles were picked up out of many cities of “Western Europe and on the defensive.”

Is there specific reason for naming “Dublin to Los Angeles” here, not other cities, such as  “Madrid to New York” being cited instead? Are these somehow metonyms for something else? Do Dublin and Los Angeles have some special connotation as a metaphor for the length and breadth of Christianity to English speakers, like how [“from California to the New York Island”](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/This_Land_Is_Your_Land) describes the span of the United States, how [“from Land’s End to John o’ Groats”](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Land's_End_to_John_o'_Groats) describes the span of the Isle of Britain, or even how “from Medina to Mecca” has a metaphoric meaning in Islam?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about ELU.

Comment: @Tchirist. Thanks for your editing, which made the intent of my question much clearer.

Comment: @Kris. I’m asking what the names of cities represent for, not culture. If my question is regarded as off-topic because of being ‘cultural’ topic, I may not be allowed to ask the meaning of the idiom such as “Carry coals to Newcastle,” “Do Roman when you are in Rome.”

Comment: You have accepted an answer that is not about the English language, right?

Comment: Kris. Aren't Dublin and Los Angeles English words? I simply asked what the names of these cities represent for in the given context. What about “Carry coals to New Castle.” I don’t know why you are tenaciously following every my question. If you hate my asking a question, please don’t read it. I accepted the answer which was appreciated to be a good answer and supported by six members out of 65 members who were interested in this question including tchirist (who kindly took the labor of editing the question to make it more sence) and you.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about world knowledge, not English language. Yoichi, this question is like asking "What country is directly south of the city of Detroit?". The question is stated in English. THat's about all there is in content though that is related to the English language.

Comment: Mitch. You cannot draw a clear-cut line between language and cultural issue. There is no standard or monolithic ‘world knowledge’. For instance most of Japanese who are Buddhists or Shintoists are not concerned about gay, abortion, and priests’ child molestations as westerners do, accordingly have no association of LA and Dublin with these cases. – Actually this question was raised in our ‘English Reading Circle.’ None of 25 members, some of whom consider themselve as internationalist had any idea about implications of ‘LA and Dublin.’ Is it better to forget about it as a Greek?

Comment: Cont'd:It’s like many people in other corners of the globe might not be so much concerned with the name of Fukushima and Yasukuni as we seriously do. Many of language, whichever language is, need to be explained culturally. Otherwise, you can’t ask about even biblical English. Also I think you’d better to pay attention that this question was once ‘held,’ ‘closed’ and ‘reopened,’ which means there are not a few members who consider the question worthwhile asking and answering even among native English speakers and particularly, non-native English speakers like me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Dublin and Los Angeles are among the (many, but certainly among the largest) cities where the church has faced legal action and complaints of child abuse, as well as allegations of significant financial fraud and personnel shuffling to cover up the allegations of abuse.

Comment: Yes.  Los Angeles has also been called “the end of the world”, relative to modern human expansion – so the expression half-works on that level too.  (”Los Angeles is like a beauty parlor at the end of the universe.” - Emily Mortimer)